# Neo4j Implementation on the Web

Tags: neo4j

Just got out of a Neo4j training session where we created a wonderfully complex database on our localhost server, but I can't figure out how I can transfer this database for use on my actual website. All of the documentation I'm finding online is about installing it to a localhost server, but how can I access and query this information via my actual website? Is it as simple as copying the graph.db folder into my public_html folder online and somehow linking it to one of the language drivers? I can't find documentation anywhere that gives a straightforward explanation. Will I need extensive knowledge of Java in order to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning on using an embedded database engine, or a standalone Neo4j server?

Comment: You can use a database hosting solution like graphenedb.com see http://neo4j.org/develop/cloud. You should probably have asked that during the training :)

Comment: I was advised during the training to read through the manual, which I assumed would be enough information on its own, but I've found it to be rather confusing instead. We didn't have enough time to cover its use in web development (which kind of surprised me!).

Comment: Regarding using it as an embedded database engine vs. a standalone server, it's hard to say because I've never worked with this kind of database before. My only experience is with MySQL databases which are very simple in comparison.

Comment: You can either use your own server or use an hosted solution: for the former, just but a server and install Neo4J on it otherwise go to graphenedb and but an instance.
The easiest way to query your Neo4J instance is via the REST interface, but if you control the server you can also use some language binding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a cloud deployed Neo4j server or install the Neo4j server on your own internet accessible server (much like mysql)

- For [EC2 / Linux](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/cloud)
- For [GrapheneDB](http://graphsarecool.blogspot.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-neo4j-20-on.html) (also available on heroku)
- For [Windows Azure](http://graphsarecool.blogspot.de/2014/03/setting-up-neo4j-201-linux-vm-on.html)

then you can use one of the many drivers to connect to the server and import data or query it. 
http://www.neo4j.org/develop/drivers